# How to select according to langague in sql?

Tags: mysql, sql, select, rows, hebrew

I have a database that contains both Hebrew and English. Unfortunately, the man who created the Data-base did a crappy job.
I need to select rows that don't contain any Hebrew in them. Does SQL/MYSQL have a way of doing that?

Comment: What does the table schema look like ?

Comment: I don't know anything about hebrew,but you could try to select * from a column or more where the vowels or whatever most used character in hebrew are not in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends a lot on the character set being used for storing the data.  A guess would be that it is UTF8 encoded.  UTF8 encoding has a particular characteristic that is useful for this purpose:  ASCII characters (the kind we use in English) are only one byte.  Hebrew characters would require more than one byte.

So, you can try this:

```
where char_length(col) = length(col)
```

If you know that the strings always begin with an alphabetic character, then something like:

```
where left(col1, 1) between 'a' and 'z'
```

might also work.

Comment: Briliant! worked like a charm.
Also, I remembered that my mom is an SQL expert so she helped me modify the code a little bit :-)
<pre>           
SELECT * FROM [namedb]
 WHERE
 (left(name, 1) between 'a' and 'z' OR name is NULL OR name = ' ') and
 (left(author, 1) between 'a' and 'z' OR author is NULL OR author = ' ')
order by name;          </pre>

Answer (score 0):

Hi As the the column contain both english and Hebrew  the data type must be nvarchar,

In SQL SERVER I DID THIS

```
SELECT CASE 
    WHEN CHARINDEX('?',CONVERT(VARCHAR,'2232d@❤##'))>0 THEN 'YES' 
    ELSE 'NO' 
END
```

this will tell you if a value is hebrew if yes else in english.

Use Locate in place of Char Index

Please let me know if this is of any help.

I am just giving you an upper idea. If you need any further help please tell.

Regards